# Android webview load html, then set variable, then load script

Tags: android, kotlin, android-webview

I have this html in my assets folder.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var publicKey = ""

        function setPublicKey(key) {
            publicKey = key;

            var url = '<' + 'script src="https://<my_url>?onload=loadChallenge" async defer>' + '<' + '/script>'
            document.write(url);
        }

        function loadChallenge() {
            //do some stuff using the publicKey
            new Thing( {public_key: publicKey } )
        }
     </script>
<div id="CAPTCHA"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to load it into a webview, pass and set the publicKey, and then load the script that uses the `onLoad` param in the url.

So I'm loading my html into the webview and using this WebViewClient:

```
private val myWebViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
        override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
            view?.loadUrl("javascript:setPublicKey($publicKey)")
        }
    }
```

`document.write(url)` isn't working.  `document.write("anything")` isn't working.

I'm not married to this solution, I just need a solution that lets me load the html, then set the publicKey, and then load that script.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you set javascript enabled to true, like this **myWebViewClient.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true**?

Comment: yep :( all the flags are set

Comment: In Java we need to wrap the string param in quotes like that "javascript:setPublic( ' " + publicKey + " ' )"  maybe you need to do something like that in Kotlin. Do You successfully loaded the html in webview?

Comment: No, that's not it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it with this script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var publicKey = ""

    function setPublicKey(key) {
        publicKey = key;
        console.log("public key: " + publicKey);
        var url = "<my_url>?onload=loadChallenge"
        var s = document.createElement('script');
        s.setAttribute('src', url);
        s.async = true;
        document.body.appendChild(s);
    }

    function loadChallenge() {
        //do some stuff using the publicKey
        new Thing( {public_key: publicKey } )
    }
 </script>
```

First I load the html into the webview from the file.

The webview is using this WebViewClient:

```
private val myWebViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
    override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
        view?.loadUrl("javascript:setPublicKey(`$publicKey`)")
    }
}
```

This waits for the html to load and calls `setPublicKey()` which sets the key and loads the script.

Works like a charm.